# Navigating Jenkins with big number of (irrelevant) projects

Tags: jenkins, hudson

*Disclaimer: I'm new to this team and never seen Jenkins before, so I may have wrong assumptions about what is default in Jenkins and what has already been (heavily) customized.  My apologies.*

As a general intuition when navigating in tree structures, when I want to quickly switch to another item, I use topmost common item in the breadcrumb trail and descend from there.

However structure in Jenkins seems to be some compromise between filtering and tree-like: sometimes the trail does contain parents (i.e. Views) but sometimes it only contains root, (named "Jenkins", leading to "Default") a view and project as a leaf .

Since default view always displays all projects, it makes it unpractical for navigation as this takes unnecessarily long (about 5s for ~500 items) to load.  In fact, I hardly ever want to see the full list at all.

Now while I can create "My views" that display projects based on my selection, and configure a very short and fast view to display instead of "Default", I did not find a way how to make it useful for navigation.  I'd imagine one of these solutions:

- make breadcrumb trail root "Jenkins" lead to "my-fast-view" instead of the big
  "Default"
- make "my-fast-view" stay in the trail, e.g. "Jenjins -> my-fast-view -> my-project"

  Well it actually does behave this way (with addition of including my name in the trail
  which is not an obstacle) *most of the time*.  When I select the project *from the
  Build Queue", trail changes to "Jenkins > my-project", from which point I can't get to
  "my-fast-view" quickly
- include "My views" item somewhere on every page and use it as main navigation point
  (forget about the breadcrumbs)

Any hints?

Comment: Could you show some sreenshots or something? Right now I find it hard to imagine what you are trying to achieve ;-)

Comment: Sorry but for now I can't imagine a screen-shot illustrating what I mean *and* not leaking internal information... ...unless a greyish pixelized blob with Jenkins logo is illustrative ;)

Comment: Wouldn't bluring out the project/view names be sufficiant? I just want to know what view you expect when you click somewhere. But maybe I'm just too tired to get it on a friday afternoon ;-)

Comment: @stonedsquirrel No hurries, sure I don't expect this to boost my productivity so promptly I could catch up with this week... :D

Comment: Alright, then I'll take another look at it tomorrow :-)